# Mixed Content Page: requested an insecure stylesheet error

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, https

I have a website working on it. when i open any page with http:// protocol, every thing is loaded correctly, but when i try to load the page with https protocol, the page loaded but without css and javascript file. 
 The console shows the following errors.

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=login' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://www.example.com/site_map.html'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I figured that the problem is the browser can not load any css files when it requested by https protocol. 
The problem is with htaccess file, because when i removed it, the css files loaded correctly.

The page and css files loaded to browser with https in their urls like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/includes/templates/classic/css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.example.com/includes/templates/classic/css/style2.css">
```

when the browser tries to load the css files, it is redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/site_map.html
```

How can i make htaccess allow https to open the css and js files in a specific folder? 
 
Thanks

**UPDATE**
The htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 
###############################################################################
# Common directives
###############################################################################
# NOTE: Replace /shop/ with the relative web path of your catalog in the "Rewrite Base" line below:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

#RewriteBase /

###############################################################################
# Start Ultimate SEO URLs
###############################################################################

# Original (unchanged) URL formats
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*)-p(.*)\.html$ /index.php?main_page=$4&cPath=$2&sort=$5&page=$3
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-ez-(.*).html$ index.php?main_page=page&id=$2 [L]

# All other pages
# Don't rewrite real files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule   index.html$  index.php [QSA] 


# 480 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 DAYS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# 2 HOURS
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteRule   index.html$  index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

You don't allow SSL requests (443 port number is used for HTTPS requests). Try removing these lines.

Answer (score 18):

If you are able to serve CSS etc over HTTPS, the best solution is to [use `//` as the scheme](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for asset URLs.

That means "use the same scheme (sometimes called *protocol*) as the parent document", i.e. use `https` if the page uses `https`. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//mysite.com/styles.css">
<script src="//mysite.com/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: You missed URL's domain

Comment: " i.e. use https if the page uses https" confused me for a sec, but your examples did the trick: just replaced all http:// by //

Comment: // caused the file not to be found.

Answer (score 15):

Most probably inside your html code you have something like

```
<link href="http://someSite.com/css/someStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you should change this to

```
<link href="https://someSite.com/css/someStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

also the page you are referring to is .html not css, but i guess that is a typo ...

Comment: When the page is loaded with https and css files url also used https. for when the browser oped it, the server response with redirect page which is 'http://www.example.com/site_map.html' in my case

Comment: i had a http in my css file. changing to htpps also worked. thanks!

Comment: @loannis Loukeris, 'http' and 'hhtps' should be dynamic. User can browse using any one. Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was.  It also makes the page loads faster as well.  So that helps me kills two birds with one stone.

Comment: best practices states you should never put the domain in your code.

Answer (score 8):

Experienced similar error in Drupal 8.0.1

**Error** - *Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS*.

**Solution** - Open .htaccess file and add the following line
  **Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"**

Comment: You help to resolve this matter came from laravel app hosted on the AWS beanstalk environment. I just added the text into my public/ .htaccess file. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @soumya, This solution worked for me in Apache as well :)

Answer (score 4):

You may also need to check your
**WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** under General Settings and make sure your URLs are https://www.yourdomain.com