# Why is my css getting blocked (HTML5)?

Tags: css, html

I am writing in HTML5 and I am trying to get my application to read a .css from online which shouldn't be a problem.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>"
```

Error Received:

[image: Error]

How do I make this unblocked or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: use `https` instead of `http` in your code

Comment: Please the jsFiddle feature to paste some code   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks, This worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixed Content Page: requested an insecure stylesheet error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434786/mixed-content-page-requested-an-insecure-stylesheet-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message, it's complaining that you're using an HTTP resource on an HTTPS page. It looks like you simply have to use HTTPS for the CSS, too.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `http:` like bellow

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

> import fonts from `https://...` url

[**google font reference**](https://fonts.google.com/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto');
p:first-child{font-family: 'Roboto';}
p:last-child{font-family: 'Lato';}
```

```html
<p>https://fonts.google.com<p>
<p>https://fonts.google.com<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying required font and paste it in your custom style sheet.