# Fonts not loading after setting up Cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, fonts, cloudflare

I recently set up Cloudflare on one of my domains and the custom fonts I had selected are no longer showing up. It is a wordpress site build using Tatsu page builder. If you can provide any assistance on how to get the fonts to show up correctly I would greatly appreciate it. Domain is https://www.womensleaguecdc.org/

Thanks!

Comment: press F12 and check the errors in you console, there are a few that should solve your problem, if you fix them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like where you're calling in the font you're doing it from http instead of https. Throwing errors:

```
The page at 'https://www.womensleaguecdc.org/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.womensleaguecdc.org/wp-content/uploads/typehub/custom/loyola-pro-light/styles.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

If you have access to where they are linked you can add s to http. It should then allow it to load in. More details can be found here:

[Mixed Content Page: requested an insecure stylesheet error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434786/mixed-content-page-requested-an-insecure-stylesheet-error)